# Is it possible to create a global that is assigned once at the beginning of runtime and then borrowed across threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust, global

`lazy_static` doesn't work because I need to assign to this variable at runtime after some user interaction. `thread_local` doesn't work because I need to read this variable across threads.

From a system perspective, I think what I'm trying to do should be simple. At the beginning of execution I'm single threaded, I initialize some things, and then I `tokio::spawn` some tasks which only need to read those things.

I can get past the problem by using a mutex, but I don't really see why I should need to use a mutex when I can guarantee that no tasks will ever try to get mutable access other than at the very beginning of runtime when I'm still in a single thread. Is there a better way that using a mutex?

This is what I have so far, in case anyone is curious:

```rust
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref KEYPAIRSTORE_GLOBAL: Mutex<KeypairStore> = Mutex::new(KeypairStore::new());
}

// ...
// at top of main:
let mut keypairstore = KEYPAIRSTORE_GLOBAL.lock().unwrap();
*keypairstore = KeypairStore::new_from_password();

// somewhere later in a tokio::spawn:
let keypair_store = KEYPAIRSTORE_GLOBAL.lock().unwrap();
let keypair = keypair_store.get_keypair();
println!("{}", keypair.address());
```

I don't see why I need to use this mutex... I'd be happy to use `unsafe` during assignment, but I'd rather not have to use it every time I want to read.

Comment: If it's "at the beginning," then can you assign the variable _before_ any new threads are created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, you need the `Mutex` because you are mutating it after it is initialised. Instead, do the mutation during the initialisation:

```
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref KEYPAIRSTORE_GLOBAL: KeypairStore = {
        let mut keystore = KeypairStore::new_from_password();
        // ... more initialisation here...
        keystore
    }
}

// somewhere later in a tokio::spawn:
let keypair = KEYPAIRSTORE_GLOBAL.get_keypair();
println!("{}", keypair.address());
```

This is assuming that the signature of `get_keypair` is:

```
pub fn get_keypair(&self) -> Keypair;
```

Comment: Ah, yes. This is a solution... I thought this would run when I did cargo test and had discounted it. Thanks! I had a feeling I was overcomplicating things.

Comment: It's strange though, the reason I started down this journey was because doing things this way was causing the initialization(new_from_password) to run during "cargo test", but now it's not. I think maybe because keypairstore was inside another struct in lazy_static and now it's in lazy_static directly??

Comment: If you don't want it to run during tests, you cans use `#[cfg(test)]` and have an alternative implementation guarded by `#[cfg(not(test))]`.